# Substr and explode in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var result = "(55.6105023, 12.357556299999942)";
```

I would like to remove the brackets, and i thought that you could do this with substr (remove the first and last char in the string) <- But i can only manage to remove the last char if i know the length.

And then i would like to put the first number `55.6105023` into variable `lat` and the second `12.357556299999942` to variable `lng` by using explode() <-  but this does not exists in JS

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), which can take negative indices and unlike `substr()` is standardized and works in all browsers:

```
result.slice(1, -1);
```

You can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for the other part:

```
var parts = result.slice(1, -1).split(", ");
var lat = parts[0], lng = parts[1];
```

Alternatively you could use a regex:

```
var res = /^\(([\d.]+),\s*([\d.]+)\)$/.exec(result);
var lat = res[1], lng = res[2];
```

Comment: @Karem: I assume from the big green tick that you realized that `slice()` does work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first and last characters by using [substr](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp), [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) or [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp). Use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to split the string into an array on the comma. Like so:

```
var chunks = result.slice(1, -1).split(", "); 
var lat = chunks[0].trim();
var lng = chunks[1].trim();
```

I've added the trim to make sure all whitespaces are gone.

Comment: `trim()` is ECMAScript 5 and not universally supported (it's unsupported IE < 9 for example). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: @TimDown: You are right. Thanks for pointing this out. I hate that kind of things...trim is such a common function :s

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to pull out the numbers:

```
"(55.6105023, 12.357556299999942)".match(/[\d\.-]+/g);
// returns ["55.6105023", "12.357556299999942"]
```

The regex will match digits, decimal points and minus signs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = "(55.6105023, 12.357556299999942)"; 
var substring = result.substring(1, result.length - 1);
var coordinates = substring.split(",");
var lat = coordinates[0];
var lng = coordinates[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string manipulation functions like [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to parse out the numbers (or even a regular expression with matching groups), and the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) constructor to parse a number from a string:

```
var parseResult = function(s) {
  var ss = s.split(', ');
  return [Number(ss[0].slice(1)), Number(ss[1].slice(0, -1))];
};

var x = parseResult('(55.6105023, 12.357556299999942)');
x[0]; // => 55.6105023
x[1]; // => 12.357556299999942
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `substring` and `indexOf`:

```
var result = "(55.6105023, 12.357556299999942)";
var lat = result.substring(result.indexOf('(')+1, result.indexOf(','));
var lon = result.substring(result.indexOf(', ')+1, result.indexOf(')'));

alert(lat); // alerts 55.6105023
alert(lon); // alerts 12.357556299999942
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, which first converts the data into proper JSON and then into a JavaScript array:

```
str = str.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']');
var data = JSON.parse(str),
    lat = data[0],
    lng = data[1];
```